# Any alternative for getTextContent() to get the content of the xml document?

Tags: android, xml, xmlhttprequest, xml-parsing

I want to get the xml document inside my document.I tried the below code

```
fullReport.append(docs.getElementsByTagName("report").item(0).getTextContent());
```

but I am getting an error for getTextContent() ie "The method getTextContent() is undefined for the type Node".I tried its casting method & I have also tried xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar implementation.I am running in updated jdk 1.6 only.Kindly tell me how to get correct this of this error.

Comment: I need one help can you please tell me what that item(0) means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one reason may be is that getTextContent () is not defined under type Element dut to the fact your Android project target version should be less than 2.2.It is only available in the higher version of Android to enhance the lower version.Just try updating your version 2.2 or more